# POST Large amount JSON data via django rest api`

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to post large amount of JSON data (above 100mb) from react to django rest post api. I have checked with small amount of JSON data (40mb) its working fine, there is no issue. While using large data the browser is too slow and affect the system performance (Hanging). Request you to please suggest for this issue. Is anything to do with django rest api and react for sending large data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is not with django (isps and webservers) usually limit post requests sizes as they can be used for DDOS.

i don't know if you're using apache or nginx but this might directive might help  : client_max_body_size

Also have you checked if the response timed out or never reached your python code ?

Comment: Right now I'm using local ubuntu terminal for development after that will deploy IIS.

Comment: I have checked the response is not reached python code.

Comment: could you provide some context : which webserver are you using ? is it inside a container ?

Comment: im using windows server for iis hosting

Answer (score 0):

you could consider compressing json then posting it to server, and decompressing it in server side with some compression algorithm such as [zlib-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zlib-js?activeTab=readme), [zlib-python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) ...

Comment: You could use the  header content-encoding (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) to hardcode the compression in python